# Singleton override readResolve during serialization

Tags: java, serialization

For safe synchronization during serialization, we implemented the `readResolve` method, which returns the class object.

Where is this method defined? How does the compiler call it? How does it work?

Comment: I can recommend you a reading: Effective Java by Joshua Bloch - chapter 11. Serialization

Answer (score 0):

It is defined in the [Object Serialization Specification #3.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#5903). The compiler doesn't call it: `ObjectInputStream` calls it. It's all described there.